# ¿Cómo hago para que mi cuadro de opciones en Access tenga una opción donde muestre todas las opciones para todos mis registros?

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

Tengo una pequeña base en la cual veo por medio de un formulario las ventas por productos, frutas y verduras, este filtro entre frutas y verduras lo hago con una cuadro de opciones en otro formulario, al seleccionar frutas en este cuadro sólo se muestran las ventas de frutas y al seleccionar verduras pasa lo mismo, añadí una opción para ver ambos productos con el siguiente criterio en la consulta: SiInm([Formularios]![VENTAS]![Marco1]=3,1 O 2,[Formularios]![VENTAS]![Marco1]), pero al seleccionar "Ambos" en el cuadro de opciones (el cual tiene asignado el número 3) no se me muestra ningún registro.

[image: Ventas por frutas]

[image: Venta por verduras]

[image: Selección de ambos productos]

[image: Consulta en la que se basa el formulario]

Comment: Si quieres ver frutas y verduras, entonces lo que quieres es no aplicar ningún filtro sino ver todo ¿no?, con lo que el campo de Criterio debería estar vacío. O prueba a poner `IN(1,2)` EN VEZ DE `1 O 2`

Comment: Hola, primero, gracias por contestar, y segundo, no, lo que yo quiero es poder ver sólo frutas o sólo verduras o ambos, o sea tres opciones, ya intente poner In(1,2) en mis criterios, pero sigue sin arrojarme nigún registro.